# Поменять строчки местами в векторе векторов

Tags: c++, vector

Нужна помощь,не получаеться поменять строчки местами в векторе векторов пробовал через swap,но у меня ничего не вышло.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    int n, m;
    cout << "Введите колличество строк" << endl;
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Введите колличество элементов в строке" << endl;
    cin >> m;

    vector < vector <int> > a(n, vector <int>(m)); // Объявление вектора на n строк по m элементов 

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)     
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) 
        {
            cin >> a[i][j]; 
        }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) 
            cout << a[i][j] << ' '; 
        cout << endl;
    }
    swap(a[n], a[m]);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ты пытаешься поменять строку с номером n, это больше чем зарезервировано под вектор (индексация с 0, значит последний номер строки n-1)

Comment: И все же я не понял что нужно изменять...

Comment: @OlexandrDzynhar, нужно правильно указать индексы тех строк, которые вы хотите поменять местами.Например, чтобы поменять первую с последней, пишите так: `swap(a[0], a[n-1]);`